# camel - how to move files outside docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application inside a container and I use camel to read some files, but I need to tell camel that start reading outside the container and later move the same file to a specific path that is also outside the container,  can someone help me?,

This is my code:

```
@Component
public class Controlador extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    Procesador objProcesador;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("ftp://user@ip:port?password=password&passiveMode=true&delete=true").streamCaching().convertBodyTo(InputStream.class).process(objProcesador).to("/var/lib");
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [move](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) URI option instead of delete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905462/how-to-rename-and-move-the-file-on-ftp-once-processed-by-camel

Comment: Yes, that would move the file but how can I specify a path that is outside the container?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with "outside of container". If this mean move file on remote FTP server, then "move" option inherited from camel-file2 component should work

Comment: I mean that I can't use ftp because the file that I want to move is on the docker host, for example, the file would be on /var/lib/files but if I add that path in my jar, it would search where the jar is running and not on the host, am I explain myself?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by outside a container? If you mean a path on the host running the container you  need to share that path as a volume. Set the volume when you use `"docker run.."` or in your Dockerfile. If you mean Camel should fetch a file via ftp or sftp ensure the container can access that site first.

Comment: yes I need a file from the host, but is it possible to read and move a file between two different paths?, beacause I need to read the file from /mnt/files but later move the file to another location on the host for example /var/lib/files

Comment: Yes it is. Both paths must be mouted as [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes), so container can access it. Then you can use &move option with relative or absolute path to mounted volume.

Comment: Any path you need on the host needs to be mounted as a volume in order for the container to reach it.